# Writing functions in R

Tags: r

I am getting familiar with R after a good amount of experience with SAS and I've quickly discovered that functions in R do NOT behave like macros in SAS, so I need a little guidance.

Here is my function that doesn't work:

```
dscore<-function(data,var){

  ave<-mean(data$var)
  sd<-sd(data$var)

  data$vardscore<-(data$var-ave)/sd


  return(data)
}
```

I am using the cars dataset

```
cars<-dscore(cars,speed)
```

Should give me back the cars dataframe with an additional column that is the Cohen D value for the speed variable for that observation.

I get all sorts of crazy errors, so I would appreciate any help.

edit:

```
dbind<-function(data,var){
  var<-substitute(var)
  var<-as.character(var)
  ave<-mean(data[,var])
  sd<-sd(data[,var])
  name<-paste0(var,"dscore")
  data$name=((data[,var]-ave)/sd)
  return(data)
}
```

I need help dynamically naming the new column based on the input. Right now I just get a new column named "name"

Comment: The big thing to remember is that SAS functions on text-replacement, so `data$var` makes sense to translate to `cars$speed` in that context. R on the other hand, doesn't, so will pass a copy of `cars`, represented as `data`, but will then literally go looking for `data$var` - and this variable of course doesn't exist in the dataset copied from `cars`.

Comment: The actual column names should only be character-literals when passed to functions, unless of course you do want them evaluated. It's NOT that functions do not behave like macros (although that is also true)  but at least in this case rather that arguments get evaluated. The interpreter looked for a variable in the calling environment named 'speed' and didn't find it. (AND it's generally not a good idea to use `"$"` inside functions.  You will be happier if you learn to use `"["`)

Comment: As a side note, you can also only pass what is necessary to a function. For your example: `dscore <- function(x) (x-mean(x))/sd(x)` and then do `cars$vardscore <- dscore(cars$speed)` or `cars["vardscore"] <- dscore(cars[,"speed"])`

Comment: Don't try to do everything at once - take my `dscore` function from my above comment, then you can do: `cars[paste(names(cars),"dscore",sep=".")] <- lapply(cars, dscore)` and everything solved.

Comment: Or sometimes you don't have to rewrite something existing. In this case, the function `scale`.

Comment: @Pascal - true that - but I assume this is a simplified example for the point of discussion. Replace `dscore` with `scale` above and you're in business too.

Comment: @thelatemail Right. It is only to point out that in some cases, there is no need to write something which already exist somewhere in a R package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the `$` sign with a variable. Try instead:

```
data[,var]
```

where `var` must be a character, e.g. `"speed"`

```
dscore<-function(data,var){

  ave<-mean(data[,var])
  sd<-sd(data[,var])

  data[,paste0(var,"dscore")]<-(data[,var]-ave)/sd


  return(data)
}

cars<-dscore(cars,var="speed")
```

Comment: Thanks, my issues now is that the column that is being added is named vardscore instead of speeddscore, so I need help dynamically naming the new column based on the input.

Comment: @CarlGanz Same feedback, use `[,` instead of `$`

Answer (score 3):

```
dscore<-function(data,var){
  ave<-mean(data[,var])
  sd<-sd(data[,var])
  data$vardscore<-(data[,var]-ave)/sd
  return(data)
}
cars<-dscore(cars, "speed")
```